# Update a MobX nested observable.map property

Tags: mobx

There is a simplified store with an `observable.map`:

```
class ThStore {
    constructor() {
        this.store = mobx.observable.map({});
    }
}

mobx.decorate(ThStore, {
    _store: mobx.observable,
}
```

The store holds data with this format (abbreviated), it is a javascript object literal that is managed by `mobx` as an `observable.map`. The data itself is a collection of items keyed with its `id` that has some nested child collection with the same format:

```
 {
    "some-id": {
        id:"some-id",
        label:"some-value",
        childs: {
             "child-id": {...some properties},
             "other-child-id": {...some properties},
        }
    },
    "other-id": {
        id:"other-id",
        label:"other-value",
        childs: {
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

A change in a whole entry in the store works as expected

```
storeInstance.store.set("some-id", newItem);
```

But I cannot find a way to update only a property of an item. Getting an item gives a Proxy object which I don't know how to use to update some of its properties.

```
const item = storeInstance.store.get("childs");
// item is a Proxy instance and has no `.get` method to retrive a child
```

Trying to update the item like this works, but forces to update all the item and not just the required property triggering more re-renders than necesary.

```
const copiedItem = mobx.toJS(storeInstance.store.get("some-id"));

// This change does not trigger mobx 
copiedItem.child["child-id"].property = someValue;

// This change does but forces updating all the item
storeInstance.set("some-id", copiedItem);
```

So I don't know how to do fine grainned updates to a `mobX` store using `observable.map` with nested child maps.

**EDIT**: the problem is that the nested `childs` property is not converted to an `observable.map` by `mobx` but is left as a plain object. How can be the nested property be forced to be converted to `observable.map`?

Comment: Just a comment: although observables are _deep_ and _mutable_ by default, you either have to create a new instance of an object you pass. Alternatively you can create an action which traverses through the object with `.entries(([key, val]) => logic magic);` function and there have the target key as your function parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I just convert all my keyed object collections and child collections to `Map` instances, so `observable` converts all of them to `observable.maps` no matter how deep in the tree.